# Model inheritance - Repository Pattern with IoC

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository, inversion-of-control

I am new to IoC and Repository Pattern. I was able to do some test project and it works. But, I am not so sure if what I implemented is a good practice. The test project I have created have all the repositories in place as well as a working interface with a dummy data. But what I want is that my project should not be able to know the concrete types of my models because the initial version should be implemented using MSSQL, and the second version would be a mix of MSSQL and NoSQL(for reads and logging). The models might have different properties or structures from MSSQL to NoSQL (or whatever i might use in the future)

So I tried to create an interface for each model:

```
public interface ISearchResult
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the repository:

```
public interface ISearchRepository<T> where T: class, ISearchResult
{
    IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(string keyword, IEnumerable<string> regions, IEnumerable<string> industries,IEnumerable<string> countries, IEnumerable<string> cities, int offset);
}
```

And here's the service:

```
public interface ISearchService
{
    IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(string keyword, IEnumerable<string> regions, IEnumerable<string> industries,IEnumerable<string> countries, IEnumerable<string> cities, int offset);
}
```

Because I want to have a working GUI even without MSSQL or NoSQL entities, I have created a View Model that inherited the ISearchResult:

```
public class SearchResultViewModel : ISearchResult
{
    [Display(Name="Reference Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Website")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how it looks on my controller:

```
[SearchQueryFilter]
[GeoTargetFilter]
public ActionResult Query(SearchQueryModel searchQuery)
{
     searchQuery.Results = this._searchService.Search<SearchResultViewModel>(searchQuery.Keyword,searchQuery.Region, new List<string>() { searchQuery.Industries }, new List<string>() { searchQuery.Countries}, new List<string>() {searchQuery.City}, searchQuery.Offset)
            .ToList<ISearchResult>();

        return View(searchQuery);
 }
```

And my view would look like this:

```
@foreach (SearchResultViewModel result in Model.Results)
{
     //code to display
}
```

My question is: Is it fine to use this approach? I don't want my web application to be dependent on my data entities so that's why I came up of making my view models inherit an interface. And because I was new to IoC and Repository Pattern and only have a test project, I don't know if my solution would be more of a problem in the long run.

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to implement an interface in your view model in order to create a separation between your web application and your data entities. Your view model should *belong* to your web application and should *itself* be independent of your data entity.

So, instead of:

```
_searchService.Search<SearchResultViewModel>(x);
```

You should have, in your controller:

```
var result = _searchService.Search<SomeEntity>(x);
var model = new SearchResultsViewModel
{
    Name = result.Name,
    Desc = result.Desc,
    Url = result.Url
};
return View(model);
```

The view model belongs to the web application and is responsible for containing the data passed from controller to view (and back) - it should have nothing to do with your service layer (or any other layer of your application).

`SomeEntity` is a concrete class, in the form of whatever your search service exposes. Your controller will consume this in the same way as any other application would and then compile a view model for passing to and from views. You might even find that `SomeEntity` is more or less identical to `SearchResultsViewModel` initially; however, they are still distinct entities as the requirements of the view might change independently of the search service.

Comment: so how should I declare "SomeEntity" ? should it be an abstract class? or should it be concrete that is diffrent from MSSQL or NoSql entities?

Comment: Updated my answer - see last paragraph.